# iOS: navigation bar title - two colors

Tags: ios, objective-c

My navigation bar title has two word, one word I want it blue and the other word I want it white.
There is anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create a `UILabel`. Set its `attributedText` to an attributed string with the two colors.

Then set the label as the view controller's navigation item's `titleView`.

Add the following to the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller:

```
NSAttributedString *twoColors = ... // your two color string
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.attributedText = twoColors;
[label sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```